# Icons not displayed for menu items

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to add an icon to menu items.
This does not work:

```
  android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_save"
  android:drawableLeft="@android:drawable/ic_menu_save"
```

Could I be doing sth wrong?

xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:id="@+id/delete"
          android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_save"
          android:title="@string/delete" />
</menu>
```

java:

```
@Override
    public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v,
            ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
        super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);

        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.context_menu, menu);
    }
```

Comment: Can you post the whole <MenuItem>? And I don't think you need android:drawableLeft.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

try this :

android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_save"

also check this link will help :

http://www.tanisoft.net/2010/09/android-context-menu-with-icon.html

hope this help

Comment: `error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'icon' with value '@drawable/ic_menu_save')`

Comment: you must have icon saved in drawable then refer to it as above, are you already save it

Comment: is so and gave you no resource found , make clean project ,then it will recognize it or if not restart eclipse then it will found it .

Comment: post menu xml better to evaluate it